# multiplying a value from one relation by a sum from another relation for each record

Tags: javascript, laravel, eloquent

---

I am trying to calculate something here.
So basically what I am doing is fetching all profiles with their projects, and eager load relations bids and timers on these projects. Every project has one bid and it has a value, and every project can have multiple timers.

What I want to do is for every project, calculate the difference between the started_at and stopped_at for the timers and get it as a sum in hours, and multiply it by the value of the bid for the very same project, and then return it all as a sum.
Basically I want to get the total amount the person has earned (for every project all timers durations in hours * bid value).

Currently I am trying to calculate all that in javascript and this is what I have so far:

```
            calculateTotalAmountEarned(projects) {
            let totalAmount = 0;
            let totalHours = 0;
            let total = moment.duration(0);
            let value = 0;
            projects.forEach((project) => {
                project.timers.forEach((timer) => {
                    if(timer.stopped_at) {
                        let started = moment(timer.started_at);
                        let stopped = moment(timer.stopped_at);
                        let time = moment.duration(stopped.diff(started));

                        total.add(time)
                    }
                    totalHours = +(total.asHours()).toFixed(0);
                })
                project.bids.forEach((bid) => {
                    value = bid.value
                })

                totalAmount = totalHours * value
            })

            return totalAmount
        },
```

well right now it returns the sum of all timers across all projects multiplied by the value of a single bid on a single project.

what I am getting right now is: 55 hours which is the duration from all timers of all projects for a profile, multiplied by 14 which is the value of a single bid.

example input and expected output:
project 1: 3 timers each with a duration of 1 hour -> sum 3 hours, value of the bid is 14
project 2 same as project 1 etc

expected result is (project 1 = 3 * 14) + (project 2 => 3 * 14) and so on for all projects

```
"projects":[  
     {  
        "id":1,
        "timers":[  
           {  
              "id":1,
              "name":"dfdsf",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:22",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:25",
              "created_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:22",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:25",
           },
           {  
              "id":2,
              "name":"dfdsf343",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:28",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:30",
              "created_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:28",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:30",
           },
           {  
              "id":3,
              "name":"dfdsf343zzxccz",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:33",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:35",
              "created_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:33",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:35",
           },
           {  
              "id":4,
              "name":"dfdsf343zzxcczfgfg",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:37",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:40",
              "created_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:37",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-23 11:48:40",
           },
           {  
              "id":5,
              "name":"asdfsadf",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-24 10:44:51",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-24 11:12:55",
              "created_at":"2018-05-24 10:44:51",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-24 11:12:55",
           },
           {  
              "id":7,
              "name":"twqetqwtq",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-24 11:13:45",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-24 12:08:22",
              "created_at":"2018-05-24 11:13:45",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-24 12:08:22",
           },
           {  
              "id":9,
              "name":"asd",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-24 12:08:29",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-24 12:42:13",
              "created_at":"2018-05-24 12:08:29",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-24 12:42:13",
           },
           {  
              "id":11,
              "name":"1234",
              "project_id":1,
              "profile_id":2,
              "started_at":"2018-05-24 13:23:34",
              "stopped_at":"2018-05-26 08:30:41",
              "created_at":"2018-05-24 13:23:34",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-26 08:30:41",
           }
        ],
        "bids":[  
           {  
              "id":1,
              "value":"34",
              "created_at":"2018-05-22 12:25:37",
              "updated_at":"2018-05-22 12:25:55"
           }
        ],
```

Ok so this is the relevant information for one project - its timers and bids - there's always one bid. the expected output is the difference between stopped_at and started_at in hours for each timer summed and multiplied by the bids value. This repeated for every other project and all that summed as final result. I hope you understood my explanation

Comment: So what is the question? Does something not work properly?

Comment: Can you give an example input, and the expected output please?

Comment: well right now it returns the sum of all timers across all projects multiplied by the value of a single bid on a single project.

example input and expected output:
project 1: 3 timers each with a duration of 1 hour -> sum 3 hours, value of the bid is 14
project 2 same as project 1 etc

expected result is (project 1 = 3 * 14) + (project 2 => 3 * 14) and so on for all projects

Comment: @Echo Preferably in JSON format...

Comment: @user184994 having hard time formatting the json, do you really need it? the relevant fields are in the code: for a project's timer the started_at and stopped_at fields, and for a project's bid the bid value

Comment: Just tying to help you. It would be much easier if we could see the input you're working with, and how you expect the output to be formatted

Comment: @Echo: Yes we definitely need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

It uses the `.reduce` function to reduce the projects into a total.

(Alternately, if I understand the issue correctly, by moving the declaration of `total`, `totalHours`, and `value` inside the `project.forEach` callback, you should just be able to replace `totalAmount = totalHours * value` with `totalAmount += totalHours * value` to get the correct value using your original function)

```js
let projects = [{
  "id": 1,
  "timers": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "dfdsf",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:22",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:25",
      "created_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:22",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:25",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "dfdsf343",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:28",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:30",
      "created_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:28",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:30",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "dfdsf343zzxccz",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:33",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:35",
      "created_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:33",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:35",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "dfdsf343zzxcczfgfg",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:37",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:40",
      "created_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:37",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-23 11:48:40",
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "asdfsadf",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-24 10:44:51",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-24 11:12:55",
      "created_at": "2018-05-24 10:44:51",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-24 11:12:55",
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "twqetqwtq",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-24 11:13:45",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-24 12:08:22",
      "created_at": "2018-05-24 11:13:45",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-24 12:08:22",
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "asd",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-24 12:08:29",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-24 12:42:13",
      "created_at": "2018-05-24 12:08:29",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-24 12:42:13",
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "1234",
      "project_id": 1,
      "profile_id": 2,
      "started_at": "2018-05-24 13:23:34",
      "stopped_at": "2018-05-26 08:30:41",
      "created_at": "2018-05-24 13:23:34",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-26 08:30:41",
    }
  ],
  "bids": [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "34",
    "created_at": "2018-05-22 12:25:37",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-22 12:25:55"
  }],
}]

let total = projects.reduce((total, project) => {
  // Get the total time 
  let totalHours = project.timers.reduce((totalTime, timer) => {
      let started = moment(timer.started_at);
      let stopped = moment(timer.stopped_at);
      let m = moment.duration(stopped.diff(started));
      return totalTime + Math.round(m.asHours())
  }, 0);

  // Multiply by the bid value, and add to the total
  return total + totalHours * project.bids[0].value;
}, 0);

console.log("Total is", total)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: for some reason totalAmount += totalHours * value did not work for me. with your solution I am getting as a result 2.3M(which is the correct), but with += I get about 11-12M.

Comment: My bad, you also need to move the declarations of `total`, `totalHours`, and `value` down inside the `projects.forEach`